# Whats wrong with my anti_vowel program.It fails on "Hey look words"

Tags: python-2.7

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    a = []
    for i in str(text):
        a.append(i)
    print a

    v = "aeiouAEIOU0"
    for p in v:
        for e in a:
            if p == e:
                a.remove(p)

    print a

    d = ""
    for w in a:
        d = d + str(w)

    return d
```

Comment: Please follow these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? What outputs do you expect for a given input? What is wrong with it as-is? We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are removing elements from a list while iterating that same list. The loop will "lose track" of its current position in the list and thus skip some elements.

Instead of first adding all the letters to the list, then removing the ones that are vowels, you should just add those that are *not* vowels in the first place. You can do this in a single line using a list comprehension and then using `''.join` to join it to a string:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    return ''.join(a for a in text if a not in "aeiouAEIOU0")
```

This is roughly equivalent to

```
d = ""
for a in text:
    if a not in "aeiouAEIOU0":
        d += a
```